# Ways to improve first time indexing in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my application, I have a need to re-index all of the data from time to time. I have noticed that the time it takes to index data the first time (via bulk index) is significantly slower than subsequent re-indexing. In one scenario, it takes about 2 hours to perform the indexing the first time, and about 15 minutes (indexing the same data) with subsequent indexing.

While the 2 hours to index the first time is reasonable, I am curious why subsequent iterations to re-index are significantly faster.  And more so, I am wondering if there's anything I can do to improve the performance for when indexing the first time, e.g. perhaps by indicating how large the index will be, etc.

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** to strike out references to `merge_factor` as it has been **removed in ES 2.0**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_setting_changes.html#_merge_and_merge_throttling_settings

---

As **Damien** indicates, you can indeed influence (bulk) indexing settings - `refresh_interval` can be set to `-1` temporarily and set back to the default value of `1s` after you complete your bulk indexing.  <strike>Another setting to modify is the `merge.policy.merge_factor`; set it to a higher value such as `30` and then back to the default of `10` once done.</strike>

There are a number of tutorials and mailing list discussions about optimizing bulk indexing, but here's some official doc links to start with:

<strike>http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/merge/</strike>
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-update-settings/

If you haven't already tuned the memory settings for your JVM, you should. Although specific to a 512mb VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 server, these settings (http://pastebin.com/mNUGQCLY) should point you in the right direction. Basically, allocating the desired amount of RAM to Elasticsearch upon startup can improve JVM memory allocation/GC timing.

Comment: Thanks James.  This information is helpful and I will take a look at merge.policy.merge_factor and the references.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @James can you provide with the current es' official links?

Answer (score 3):

Have you defined a mapping for your types? If not, everytime ES find a new field, the mapping must be updated (and this impact the whole index).

On subsequent indexing, the mapping is already complete. So what you could do is explicitly mapping your types.

Also, you can improve speed of re-indexing by setting the `refresh_interval` to an higher value, [look at this benchmark](http://blog.sematext.com/2013/07/08/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/).

Comment: Thanks Damien.  Yes, I have a defined mapping for the types and even played with refresh_interval.  In fact, I was originally "tricked" into thinking that setting the refresh_interval to -1 was significantly improving performance, but it was actually because the re-indexing was faster than the first time indexing.