# elastic search index strategies under high traffic

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, bigdata

We use ElasticSearch for our tool's real time metrics and analytics part. ElasticSearch is very cool and fast when we are query our data. (statiticial facets and terms facet)

But we have problem when we try to index our hourly data. We collect every our metric data from other services. First we collect data from other services and save them RabbitMQ process. But when queue worker runs our all hourly data not index to ES. Usually %40 of data index in ES and other them lost.

So what is your idea about when index ES under high traffic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted answers to other similar questions:

- [Ways to improve first time indexing in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323719/ways-to-improve-first-time-indexing-in-elasticsearch/18339742#18339742)
- [Performance issues using Elasticsearch as a time window storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18742469/performance-issues-using-elasticsearch-as-a-time-window-storage/18769795#18769795) (latter part of my answer applies)

Additionally, instead of a custom 'queue worker' have you considered using a 'river'? For more information see:

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/the-river/
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/river/